# How does Hadoop get input data not stored on HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, nosql

I'm trying to wrap my brain around Hadoop and read [this excellent tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/) as well as perused the [official Hadoop docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html). However, in none of this literature can I find a simple explanation for something pretty rudimentary:

In all the contrived "*Hello World!*" (word count) introductory MR examples, the **input data** is stored directly in text files. However, to me, it *feels* like this would seldom be the case out in the real world. I would *imagine* that in reality, the input data would exist in large data stores, like a relational DB, Mongo, Cassandra, or only available via REST API, etc.

So I ask: **In the real world, how does Hadoop get its input data?** I do see that there are projects like [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) and [Flume](https://flume.apache.org/) and am wondering if the whole point of these frameworks is to simply ETL input data onto HDFS for running MR jobs.

Comment: good question, but there are also many cases in the "real world" (whatever this may imply for unreal worlds), in which hadoop gets its data from files on HDFS. You might find Hive useful for your needs...

Comment: Thanks @vefthym (+1) - then I guess the root of my question is: *How does the data get onto the HDFS in the first place?* At the very least there has to be *some* kind of upfront ETL from various heterogenous systems (again like Mongo, Cassandra, REST APIs, etc.) onto the HDFS. But I would think that these ETL processes would be so slow and labor intensive, that Hadoop (or some companion framework) would be able to load data directly from these systems on the fly, either bypassing HDFS altogether, or loading them onto HDFS JIT.

Comment: Maybe you could be interested in exploring alternative input formats other than [FileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html), for instance [DBInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.html), allowing you to access non HDFS data stored in a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually HDFS is needed in the Real world application for many reasons.

- Very high bandwidth to support Map Reduce workloads and Scalability.
- Data reliability and fault tolerant. Due to replication and by distributed nature. Required for critical data systems.
- Flexibility - You don't have to  pre-process the data to store that in HDFS.

Hadoop is designed to be write once and read many concept. Kafka, Flume and Sqoop which are generally used for ingestion are themselves very fault tolerant and provide high-bandwidth for data ingestion to HDFS. Sometimes it is required to ingest data from thousands for sources per minute with data in GBs. For this these tools are required as well as fault tolerant storage system-HDFS.

Comment: Thanks @Anshul Joshi (+1) - that makes sense. Can you then please confirm that it is typical/common for developers to use "ingestion tools" like Kafka/Flume/Sqoop/etc. to load input data into HDFS, prior to the MR job actually running? If you can confirm that or clarify/correct me on that, then I should be all set. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes it is common and is generally used in all "production" environments. And for all critical MR jobs data is only and only used from HDFS. And to prevent data loss or to maintain high throughput we have to use such ingestion tools. Hope I answered your question.